# Android Studio return to previous page and same spot on scroll bar?

Tags: android, button, scroll, back

I am working on a android app and when I hit the back button or save I got it to take me to the previous page but it takes me all the way to the top and I have to scroll all the way to bottom  each time I save. I have looked all over the internet and youtube but all I find is stuff on web page when you click back. Can anyone point me in the right direction here what I need to look up or some code to get me going. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ScrollView` you simply need to save its current position using `scroller.getScrollY()` right before switching to any different screen. Then, on `onResume()` call `scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, savedValue)` to get back to previous position. `savedValue` would of course be 0 initially. If you don't want smooth scrolling, you can call `scroller.scrollTo(0, savedValue)`.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Uh.. are you pointing towards `onSaveInstanceState()` ?